# Mathematica: How to convert scales to frequencies?

Tags: mathematica, wavelets

According to the transform $$w(u,s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }x(t) \psi ^*\left(\frac{t-u}{s}\right)dt,$$ the frequency should be $f=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2\pi s}$ (is it right?), where the discretized s' are calculated from octaves and voices, following
$$s_{\text{oct},\text{voc}}=\alpha  2^{\text{oct}-1} 2^{\text{voc}/\text{nvoc}}$$
But from one second of 20Hz's humming:

```
WaveletScalogram[ContinuousWaveletTransform[
    Table[Sin[40 Pi x] , {x, 0, 1, 1/2048}], 
    GaborWavelet[], {6, 4}, WaveletScale -> 10]]
```

one can see that coefficients mainly lie in the 4th octave (in this case $\alpha=10$ and the corresponding scale {4,4}=160), which is contrast to $f=1/(2\pi s)$. I must have got some silly errors. So what is the correct frequency formula? Thank you!

Comment: Which wavelet are you using?

Comment: As shown in the Mathematica code, GaborWavelet

Comment: To those voting to close: this topic is too old to be migrated anymore; go easy, y'all.

Comment: @Ｊ.M. Well, it should have been in MMA.SE

Comment: Sure, but that site you speak of didn't exist at the time you asked this question (otherwise, you'd have asked it there to begin with ;) ). Anyway...